# Unable to display a p:selectone in a popup

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, popup, parent-child, selectonemenu

I am aware of the selectonelistbox that primefaces provides 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/listbox.xhtml

Is there a way to get this as a popup for selection? For example, on a JSF view, if I click on a blank image (an all white image), how can I get a popup of the selectone list box, selecting a value on which closes the popup and sets the value in the parent view?

Do I need to create a new view for the poup? What should the scope be of the popup view bean?

Comment: No need to add the tags in your title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xhtml page:

```
<h:form>
    <p:graphicImage id="image" style="width:300px; height: 200px; background-color:white;" 
        url="#{yourBean.selectedImage}"  alt="No selection"
        onclick="PF('dlg').show();"/>

    <p:dialog header="Photo selection" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">

        <p:selectOneListbox value="#{yourBean.selectedImage}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Image 1" itemValue="http://oi44.tinypic.com/2mzdrvq.jpg" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Image 2" itemValue="http://oi42.tinypic.com/2itk12a.jpg" />
        </p:selectOneListbox>           

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Refresh" update="image" oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide()"/>
            </f:facet>  
        </h:panelGrid>  

    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

And in your backing bean just add the `selectedImage` property with its corresponding getter and setter methods.

```
private String selectedImage;

public String getSelectedImage() {
    return selectedImage;
}

public void setSelectedImage(String selectedImage) {
    this.selectedImage = selectedImage;
}
```

Comment: Can you please ad some text to you answer on what was wrong and what changes were needed?